# Javascript - click listener not passing all the data

Tags: javascript, onclicklistener, amp-html

I have a couple of divs containing images, text and links. They are identified by the class .feed-item. Instead of only accessing the link behind by clicking on the link, I would like to make the whole div clickable.

I could solve this easily with a onclick at the level of the DIV but now that I'm using AMP, I'm not allowed to use onclick in DIVs anymore so I tried to find a solution with a listener.

Site is: https://www.laurentwillen.be
Concerned class: .feed-item
Source code:

```
<div class="feed-item page-1" data-page="1" >
    <div class="feed-image"><amp-img class="amp_img" src="www.laurentwillen.be/pixel.gif"  width="160px" height="50px"  sizes="calc(20vw - )" srcset="https://www.laurentwillen.be/wp-content/uploads/sites/21/2019/01/avis-review-aliexpress-300x94.jpg 300w, https://www.laurentwillen.be/wp-content/uploads/sites/21/2019/01/avis-review-aliexpress-768x240.jpg 768w, https://www.laurentwillen.be/wp-content/uploads/sites/21/2019/01/avis-review-aliexpress-1024x319.jpg 1024w, https://www.laurentwillen.be/wp-content/uploads/sites/21/2019/01/avis-review-aliexpress-1400x437.jpg 1400w, https://www.laurentwillen.be/wp-content/uploads/sites/21/2019/01/avis-review-aliexpress-900x281.jpg 900w, https://www.laurentwillen.be/wp-content/uploads/sites/21/2019/01/avis-review-aliexpress-700x218.jpg 700w, https://www.laurentwillen.be/wp-content/uploads/sites/21/2019/01/avis-review-aliexpress-500x156.jpg 500w" alt="avis-review-aliexpress"></amp-img></div><div class="feed-category">Expérience d'achat</div>
    <div class="feed-text">
        <div class="feed-title">Mon avis complet sur Aliexpress.com</div>
        <div class="feed-link"><a href="https://www.laurentwillen.be/experience-dachat/mon-avis-complet-sur-aliexpress-com/">Mon avis complet sur Aliexpress.com</a></div>
        <div class="feed-description">J'ai acheté plus de 90 produits sur Aliexpress et je partage mes bonnes et mauvaises expériences pour vous aider à choisir.</div>
    </div>
```

My code:

```
feed_item = document.getElementsByClassName('feed-item');
for (a=0;a<feed_item.length;a++)
{
        feed_item[a].addEventListener("click", function(e){
        console.log(e.target.innerHTML);
        parser = new DOMParser();
        var local_html = parser.parseFromString(e.target.innerHTML, "text/html");
        link = local_html.querySelectorAll('div.feed-link a');
        console.log(link[0]);
        //document.location = link[0];
    });
}
```

If I click on the DIV border, I get the full HTML inside the div and I can parse it to retrieve the link. If I click anywhere inside the DIV (ex: on the description text), I only get the HTML for this specific area where the link is not available. I'd like to get all the html inside .feed-item instead of some child DIVs.

Do you have any idea of how I could achieve this? It has to be vanilla JS.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder ok I have added source code

Comment: @Andy where are you located? It should be fast, when I test it with  https://www.webpagetest.org/result/190126_3N_4d1a083c6170246b069d2181b0fd443d/ I'm under 3 seconds (full page)

Comment: @Andy - FWIW, if you're referring to the https://www.laurentwillen.be/ in the question, it's sub-second for me (also in the UK) on first load.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have tried something like this.

```
var elements = document.getElementsByClassName("feed-item");

var myFunction = function() {
    let link = this.querySelector('.feed-link a').getAttribute("href");     
    window.location.href = link;
};

for (var i = 0; i < elements.length; i++) {
    elements[i].addEventListener('click', myFunction, false);
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/xh5pe394/

Answer (score 1):

To "make the whole div clickable", you can put your A over your DIV:

```
<a href=...>
    <div class="feed-item ...>
```

You cannot use scripts in AMP. If you are starting in AMP, validate your page often and early at https://validator.ampproject.org/. It will help you to stay on course from all the restrictions in AMP!

Comment: Thanks, it works and it's the easiest solution but for SEO it's not a good option as I have optimized my link labels so that it only contains the keywords I want to push. With this approach, the whole div is enclosed in the link. If you think there is an alternative for AMP, I'm definitely interested. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can solve it by providing the click handler with a reference of the feed item:

```
var feed_items = document.getElementsByClassName('feed-item');
for (a=0;a<feed_items.length;a++)
{
    var feed_item = feed_items[a];
    feed_item.addEventListener("click", function() {
        var link = feed_item.querySelector('div.feed-link a');
        document.location = link.href;
    });
}
```